# have that va-va-voom

Tags: word-usage

Ever heard or used the noun va-va-voom? It is labelled informal and I wonder whether most of native speakers understand it if I use it.

> Cambridge Dictionary:
> va-va-voom
> noun [ U ]   informal humorous
> the quality of being exciting, attractive, or full of energy:
> He was elegantly dressed but he just did not **have that va-va-voom.**

Comment: I don't use it, but it was made famous by an advertising campaign for Renault cars in 2002 (I had to look it up to remember what product the campaign was for!).

Comment: Sure, it comes from French. Often written without dashes in French.

Comment: If you want us to comment on your use of it, please give a complete sentence as an example.

Comment: Yes, I have heard of it. It is informal. Yes, we would (probably) understand you, but you do need a sentence to show us how you're using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard this before, I think most native speakers would think it was odd. However, in the context of the sentence you provided, it would be roughly understood.

I would avoid using it in text though. If you want to use this phrase, it should be accompanied by a tone that indicates its meaning.

#### Edit

Following from FeliniusRex's comment, I went around and asked several other native English-speakers.

2 said they don't understand what it means.
4 said they hadn't heard it before but could guess what it meant. (One person said it's "very very odd")
1 said they had heard it before, but it "sounds funny".
1 said it was not odd to them.

I think it's totally fair to call this phrase odd.

Comment: Uncommon, yes, but odd or wrong -- no.

Comment: @FeliniusRex I did not say it was wrong. I would be surprised if someone said it, that is why I called it odd.